# Shortcut to restart the X-screen in Xubuntu like 'r' is for Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, xubuntu

Just like in Gnome-shell, wherein you can restart the X-screen with a terminal command 'r' without closing any of the running applications, is there something in Xubuntu which could serve the same purpose?

Comment: You could try `xfwm4 --replace` but I don't think its exactly restart as per say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out:

```
setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

Comment: Doesn't that kill the X server though? Such is the usual behavior for Ctrl+Alt+Backspace, and it appears to me that that's what it's setting. It isn't at all equivalent to Gnome Shell's `r`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. That's the closest to what I found out for simulating the Gnome Shell's r

Comment: I've found something much closer, which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Xubuntu user, but I did a little bit of digging. According to [this page (scroll down to the bottom)](http://www.xfce.org/about/tour44), you can create custom keyboard shortcuts in the keyboard preferences dialog.

So, you can create your own shortcut here. Choose an appropriate shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and map it to `xfwm4 --replace`.

This is basically what Gnome Shell's <kbd>R</kbd> command does, and it's completely different from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to kill the X server. When you kill the X server, every program you have open dies, too. When you run `xfwm4 --replace`, only the window manager dies and is restarted.